# How to save a BLOB data type file on a device?

Tags: php, android, mysql

Any help on how to get a file which is saved in MySQL and then save it in a folder on my mobile phone.

I am working on an android application which in some stage it selects files from the database, these files are stored as BLOB....then I would like to save those selected files on my device`(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ "/Testing/")`

Obviously I am connecting android to MySQL using PHP. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is the mysql database on the same system as the java VM running the app and the PHP interpreter?

Comment: No, mysql database is on a remote server and even my PHP scripts...I am using JSON to make Http Request and call the PHP Script then using this script I am selecting the Files saved as BLOB in MySQL. Now I want that once they are selected I save them in a Folder on my mobile. Is it possible?

Comment: Ok, I am no Android developer, but as you are programming in Java you have probably a FileWriter or something similar... why don't you just write the BLOB into a file? Where is the problem? And why is it relevant that you are using mysql?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should convert Blob to Bitmap at first, and then covert that Bitmap to a File and save this file on your external storage.
For example, if you're getting image from MySql database:

```
Blob blob = // get Blob from MySql database 
byte [] bytes = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Testing/";
File dir = new File(filePath);
File file = new File(dir, "filename.png");
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut);
fOut.flush();
fOut.close();
```